# Modelling of own Package dependencies in ROS environment

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi!
suppose I have a **method in path_planning package (my own package) and its output must be made available to a method that reside in another package called "Navigation package" (my own package)**.
How to **correctly model this scenario in ROS environment using nodes, topics etc.**

```
I am new to ROS; please help.
Many thanks.
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/84711/modelling-of-own-package-dependencies-in-ros-environment/) by [RB](https://answers.ros.org/users/6427/rb/) on ROS Answers with karma: 229 on 2013-09-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Publish the output into a message on a topic and subscribe this topic in your other package passing the message into that function.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2013-09-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [RB](https://answers.ros.org/users/6427/rb/) on 2013-09-29**:
Is there any practical hand on example related to this is available?

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2013-09-29**:
The standard ROS tutorials have those.